# Chrome extension to auto refresh a website ONLY when it's not focused

Tags: chrome

There are a ton of extensions to auto refresh a website. However I wish to auto refresh a website every X seconds as long as the window / tab is not in foreground / focused, exclusively.

Basically, I want to look for updates on a website / tab that is displayed on a 2nd screen. However, when I interact with the website I don't wish to be interrupted with automatic reloads. I don't wish to be forced to disable and enable the extension whenever I browse on such website / tab, too.

The tab should not stop auto-reloading in the background when I navigate to different pages in it.

Is there an extension that does the job for me?